Customize 404 page of nginx ingress controller on not found ingress
Nginx ingress controller returns 404 when a host is not bound to an ingress. I want to customize the 404 only in this situation. How can I achieve this, if possible at all.
Creating a custom 404 for all 404 of my back-end servers is something I don't want.

Do you mean https://serverfault.com/questions/850119/how-to-get-nginx-to-return-404-unless-a-specific-domain-name-is-requested ?

You need to setup a default backend for this
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/

The default backend is a service which handles all URL paths and hosts the Ingress-NGINX controller doesn't understand (i.e., all the requests that are not mapped with an Ingress).

